# Can't get drupal_array_get_nested_value to work

Tags: forms

I'm trying to use this helper function drupal_array_get_nested_value  and I can't seem to get it to run.  http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_array_get_nested_value/7  I have a specific field type I am looking for, and I can find it using a recursive array search, but I would rather use the helper function.  Essentially this is what I want

```
$field_type = "my_field_type";
$value = drupal_array_get_nested_value($field_type, $form);
```

but that is not working, it's wants me to pass an array.  How can I use this function to search for a string, or am I using the wrong function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function actually takes an array as the input and the first value is the array to be searched.

so your code should be as follows

```
$field_type = array('my_field_type');
$value = drupal_array_get_nested_value($form,$field_type);
```

Comment: Your answer is right, my approach is wrong.  I'm trying to find the value when I don't know what the parents will be because of nesting. So using this function where I need to supply the parent keys is not what I need.  Thanks for the answer as fixing the error let me know I was on the wrong path.